# Regex for matching a text htmltag text htmltag pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

How would I define a regex that just gets me a pattern like

text HTMLTag text HTMLTag text HTMLTag ........

Basically a unit patter is 'text HTMLTag' which can be fetched using $1 and $2 .

An exmaple data would be

```
abarelixx is a sample data for spellchecking<img src="Randomz" alt="Randomz Image">Randomz is the name of the image</img>Bigboss<img src="Randomz" alt="Randomz Image">Randomz is the name of the image</img>this is another text string
```

This need to be broken down to text HTMLTag ...and if there is no text/HTMLTag , it should return "" .

Comment: There's an `</img>` tag? Dont use regex to parse HTML. Altho you can use regex to tokenize, it can still be [complicated to tokenize HTML properly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9462104/remove-on-js-event-attributes-from-html-tags/9466152#9466152).

Comment: No, there's no such thing as a `</img>`; `img` is an empty tag. Nishant, can you clarify what you want, perhaps with additional examples?

Comment: JavaScript is capable of traversing the DOM. Get to wherever you would otherwise be using regex, and then use the childNodes array. For example, your above would be 5 nodes (with the image nodes having their own children, assuming they weren't image and instead this was valid HTML).

Comment: given that you're using the (non-existant) `</img>`closing tag, do you actually want to process xhtml? if you do, have a look into xslt processors to extract information from or transform your document using xpath expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a decent solution for this problem . Append a '>' to the beginning and '<' to the end . And then use a patter like re = /([>])([^<]+)([<])/g $2 would be all the text contents . 
And you can ofcourse use a normal HTML pattern to get the HTML tags .