# Regular expression in javascript to match outside of XML tags

Tags: javascript, regex

I want find all matches of "a" in `<span class="get">habbitant morbi</span> triastbbitique` , except "a" in tags (See below "a" between **).

`<span class="get">h*a*bbit*a*nt morbi</span> tri*a*stbbitique.`

If I find them, I want to replace them and also I want to save original tags.

This expression doesn't work:

```
var variable = "a";
var reg = new RegExp("[^<]."+variable+".[^>]$",'gi');
```

Comment: I'd suggest getting the text content first then run your regex.

Comment: You might want to check the formatting of your question.

Comment: I'm little lost on what do you really want to archive. Please clarify question and language.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "get a match"? All the matches are `a` - you know that before running the regex. Do you want to do a replacement?

Comment: Sorry, but I had problem with formatting. It would be clear now.

Comment: @Eric using regex I want to find all matches of "a" expect characters in html tags.

Comment: What do you want to do with them? Count them? Replace them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that this question isn't about parsing. This is lexing. Something that regex are regularly and properly used for.

If you want to go with regex there are a couple of ways you could do this.

- A simple hack lookahead like:

  ```
    a(?![^<>]*>)
  ```

  note that this wont handle `<` and `>` quoted in tags/unescaped outside of tags properly.
- A full blown tokenizer of the form:

  ```
    (expression for tag|comments|etc)|(stuff outside that that i'm interested in)
  ```

  Replaced with a function that does different things depending on which part was matched. If  `$1` matched it would be replaced by it self, if `$2` matchehd replace it with `*$2*`

The full tokenizer way is of course not a trivial task, the [spec isn't small](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#tokenization).

But if simplifying to only match the basic tags, ignore CDATA, comments, script/style tags, etc, you could use the following:

```
var str = '<span class="a <lal> a" attr>habbitant 2 > morbi. 2a < 3a</span> triastbbitique';

var re = /(<[a-z\/](?:"[^"]*"|'[^']*'|[^'">]+)*>)|(a)/gi;

var res = str.replace(re, function(m, tag, a){
    return tag ? tag : "*" + a + "*";
});
```

Result:

```
<span class="a <lal> a" attr>h*a*bbit*a*nt 2 > morbi. 2*a* < 3*a*</span> tri*a*stbbitique
```

Live Example:

```js
var str = '<span class="a <lal> a" attr>habbitant 2 > morbi. 2a < 3a</span> triastbbitique';

var re = /(<[a-z\/](?:"[^"]*"|'[^']*'|[^'">]+)*>)|(a)/gi;

var res = str.replace(re, function(m, tag, a){
    return tag ? tag : "*" + a + "*";
});

console.log(res);
```

This handles messy tags, quotes and unescaped `<`/`>` in the HTML.

---

Couple examples of tokenizing HTML tags with regex (which should translate fine to JS regex):

- [Remove on* JS event attributes from HTML tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9462104/remove-on-js-event-attributes-from-html-tags/9466152#9466152)
- [Regex to allow only set of HTML Tags and Attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9494143/regex-to-allow-only-set-of-html-tags-and-attributes/9499761#9499761)

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend [to *not* use a regular expression to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/422263); it's not a regular grammar, and you will experience pain for all but simple cases.

Your question is still a bit unclear, but let me try rephrasing to see if I have it right:

You'd like to get all matches of a given string in a HTML document, except for matches in `<tag>` bodies?

---

Assuming you're using jQuery or similar:

```
// Let the browser parse it for you:
var container = document.createElement()
container.innerHTML = '<span class="get">habbitant morbi</span> triastbbitique'
var doc_text  = $(container).text()

// And then you can just regex away normally:
doc_text.match(/a/gi)
```

(Even better would be to use [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/DOMParser), but that doesn't have wide browser support yet)

If you're in Node, then you want to look for some libraries that help you parse HTML nodes (like jsdom); and then just splat out all the next nodes.

Comment: This isn't actually parsing HTML. It's tokenizing the HTML, which regex is perfect for.

Comment: If the HTML is well written, sure.  But what if the `variable` includes `<` or `>` and you want to find instances of that in text nodes?  There's plenty of cases where a browser won't blink at unescaped control characters like that, and place them in text nodes instead of forming a tag.

Comment: `<a>foo < bar</a>` for instance.  You can't assume that someone was nice enough to `&lt;` that for you

Comment: And there is a regular grammar on how to tokenize it in any case.

Comment: Are you sure about that?  [The tokenization spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/tokenization.html#tokenization) seems to indicate that a stack is required to properly tokenize HTML.

Comment: I need save original tags, but using .text() method they will be lost.

Comment: Can you restrict it to a certain set of nodes?  I'm guessing that you're trying to implement highlighting for words/phrases in the body text?

Comment: One option is to talk all the text nodes directly

Comment: I meant to say "walk all the text nodes", not "talk", heh

Comment: @Nevir Yes, you are right. Yes I'm trying to implementing highlighting and probably I could restrict it to a certain set of nodes.

Comment: Kk, then I'd suggest sticking with Qtax's more pragmatic approach, unless you're dealing with a lot of HTML that is out of your control.

Comment: @Nevir, see my updated answer for an example that handles `<a>foo < bar</a>` and worse. Also the linked stuff may be of interest if you want to see some larger expressions. ;-)