# PHP - Regex to remove all occurences of event attributes

Tags: php, regex

after hours of trying i'm here to ask. i want to remove all the occurences of **js event attributes and style attribute** from POSTed text. it may or may not contain **new lines**.

Posted example text:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" onclick="unwanted_code" style="unwanted_style" ondblclick="unwanted_code" onmouseover="unwanted_code">google</a> is a search engine. There are other engines too. <a href="http://www.yahoo.com" onclick="unwanted_code" ondblclick="unwanted_code" onmouseover="unwanted_code" style="unwanted_style">yahoo</a> is another engine.
```

first try:

```
$pattern[0] = '/(<[^>]+) on.*=".*?"/iU';
$replace[0] = '$1';
$pattern[1] = '/(<[^>]+) style=".*?"/iU';
$replace[1] = '$1';
$out = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $in);
```

output:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">yahoo</a> is another engine.
```

second try:

```
$out = preg_replace_callback('/(<[^>]+) on.*=".*?"/iU', function($m) {return $m[1];}, $in);
```

output:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">yahoo</a> is another engine.
```

**output i'm trying to get is:**

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">google</a> is a search engine. There are other engines too. <a href="http://www.yahoo.com">yahoo</a> is another engine.
```

anyone helping me out?

Comment: Does it need to be a regexp-based answer?

Comment: You're probably best using some form of HTML filtering ([HTMLPurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) comes to mind) and set what tags and attributes are allowed.

Comment: yes regex-based please.

Comment: An answer here: [Remove on* JS event attributes from HTML tags](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9466152/107152), altho it doesn't include `style` it's easy to add if you really want the regex solution.

Comment: How are you going to combat people introducing `<script>` tags?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
$content = '<a href="http://www.google.com" onclick="unwanted_code" style="unwanted_style" ondblclick="unwanted_code" onmouseover="unwanted_code">google</a> is a search engine. There are other engines too. <a href="http://www.yahoo.com" onclick="unwanted_code" ondblclick="unwanted_code" onmouseover="unwanted_code" style="unwanted_style">yahoo</a> is another engine.';

$result = preg_replace('%(<a href="[^"]+")[^>]+(>)%m', "$1$2", $content);
echo $result,"\n";
```

**output:**

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">google</a> is a search engine. There are other engines too. <a href="http://www.yahoo.com">yahoo</a> is another engine.
```

Answer (score 3):

Even thought the question is tagged as [regex](/questions/tagged/regex), I'm adding this answer anyway, because it's more robust for input validation; this particular solution only accepts certain tags and restricts the allowed attributes:

```
$doc->loadHTML('<html><body>' . $html . '</body></html>');

$allowedTags = ['a' => ['href']];

$body = $doc->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0);

$elements = $body->getElementsByTagName('*');
for ($k = 0; $element = $elements->item($k); ) {
    $name = strtolower($element->nodeName);
    if (isset($allowedTags[$name])) {
        $allowedAttributes = $allowedTags[$name];
        for ($i = 0; $attribute = $element->attributes->item($i); ) {
            if (!in_array($attribute->nodeName, $allowedAttributes)) {
                $element->removeAttribute($attribute->nodeName);
                continue;
            }
            ++$i;
        }
    } else {
        $element->parentNode->removeChild($element);
        continue;
    }
    ++$k;
}

$result = '';

foreach ($body->childNodes as $childNode) {
    $result .= $doc->saveXML($childNode);
}

echo $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to preserve an attribute (href), you cannot delete them all. With this code you can achieve what you want, but with listing all the unwanted attributes:

```
preg_replace('#(onclick|style|ondblclick|onmouseover)="[^"]+"#', '', $in);
```

Maybe it can be simplyfied but this just works :)

Comment: yes that way it works but i tried to do away with one elegant regex. furthermore you have to include all other events (like onchange onmouseout etc.). another thing i learned but didnt understand is that if i remove U modifier it only removes one "on.*" attribute even if in the text there are 10.

Comment: one more thing my original regex removes some text that is in between two matches which it shouldnt remove. i didnt get that too.

Comment: No no, plenty of issues here, eg: `<a onclick = "alert('lol')">1</a>`, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/9466152/107152 for a more comlete regex. ;-)

Comment: my aim is for malicious code. because normal users wouldnt craft bad POST content. they just write and post.

Comment: A more simplified version: preg_replace('/(on.*?|style)=".*?"/', ' ', $in)

Comment: @Hawkeye, nope. That doesn't even work on the example I just posted.

Comment: @Qtax I usually play with regex tryouts here:
[link](http://www.functions-online.com/preg_replace.html)
Works for me.